# Can the chance to block limit of 75% bypassed?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

[Provoke](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/active/provoke) increases the change to hit by 50%. If I have already 50%, will I get 100%? Or will it be clipped to 75%?

Comment: It's pretty trivial to test this, but the answer is; the chance to block hard limit can't be passed.

Comment: `Hit Me : Gain 50% increased Block Chance for 4 seconds after casting Provoke.` If there's a hard limit, it won't be passed. If there's no limit, it then depends if the gained 50 is additive (50 + 50 = 100) or multiplicative (50 + (50 * 50%) = 75%). So if the limit is 75%, bet they made it multiplicative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your block chance will increase up to 100% (I don't think it goes past 100% on the sheet) but your actual chance to block will be 75%.

Anything past 75% is only useful for things like Justice Lantern's passive, which gives you damage reduction equal to 40(45?)-55% of your block chance.

i.e. if you have 100% block chance* then you will get 55% damage reduction but your chance to block will still be hard-capped at 75% (although your 'sheet' stats will show 100% block chance).

*achievable even without provoke, you can use 'Hold Your Ground' passive and Blood Brother in cube for some 60% block chance, plus 16% with Justice Lantern and 20% from shield, the common setup for Invoker's Crusader.